# No Credentials Error - Using boto3 and aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I am using python and jupyter notebook to read files from an aws s3 bucket, and I am getting the error 'No Credentials Error:Unable to locate credentials' when running the following code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

I believe I need to put my access key somewhere, but I am not sure where. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have AWS CLI installed, just do a simple `aws configure`. Then you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! That is giving me ' 
    aws configure
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax' . Do you know why this might be?

Comment: I also tried 'awscli configre' and got the same syntax error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, it means AWS CLI is not installed. Please follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html) and install it first.

Comment: I have done this above:  pip install awscli --user, does that not install it?

Comment: Should everything in the guide be done in the terminal? Rather than the jupyter notebook?

Comment: I installed aws cli according to the guide, and am still getting the same syntax error. Does something need to be installed in the jupyter notebook that I am working with?

Comment: AWS CLI isn't required. This approach (specifying credentials directly) might be easier for you. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html